# JPA Hibernate JAXB Lazy initialization

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jaxb

I am converting table data into xml. I am using jaxb to achieve the same. I am using the same hibernate pojo for jaxb as well. I am using JPA repository to do DB operations.

My user table is a reference in many other tables. But I want data from users and roles table only.  User Pojo class given below:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.mypersonal.model.User.UserAllowedContTypes, no session or session was closed] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.mypersonal.model.User.UserAllowedContTypes, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:267)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:582)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:325)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.writeToResult(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
    at 







@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Cloneable, Serializable {

    /** Serial Version UID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -558971439L;

    /** Use a WeakHashMap so entries will be garbage collected once all entities 
        referring to a saved hash are garbage collected themselves. */
    private static final Map<Serializable, Integer> SAVED_HASHES =
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<Serializable, Integer>());

    /** hashCode temporary storage. */
    private volatile Integer hashCode;


    /** Field mapping. */
    @XmlElement(name = "activeStatus")
    private String activeStatus;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private String address;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private String allowdrmcontent;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private String city;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private Set<CmsUserAllowedContType> cmsUserAllowedContTypes = new HashSet<CmsUserAllowedContType>();

    /** Field mapping. */
    private Set<CmsUserFtpDetails> cmsUserFtpDetailss = new HashSet<CmsUserFtpDetails>();



    /** Field mapping. */
    private String createdBy;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private Date createdOn;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private String email;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private String firstName;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private PublishingGroup fkPublisher;
    /** Field mapping. */
    @XmlElement(name = "role")
    private CmsRoleMaster fkRole;
    /** Field mapping. */
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private Integer id = 0; // init for hibernate bug workaround
    /** Field mapping. */
    private String lastName;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private Date modifiedOn;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private String password;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private Long phoneNumber;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private Integer pincode;
    /** Field mapping. */
    @XmlElement(name = "username")
    private String username;


    @Basic( optional = true )
    @Column( name = "active_status"  )
    public String getActiveStatus() {
        return this.activeStatus;

    }

    public void setActiveStatus(final String activeStatus) {
        this.activeStatus = activeStatus;
    }


    @Basic( optional = true )
    @Column( length = 45  )
    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;

    }

    public void setAddress(final String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    @Basic( optional = true )
    @Column( length = 45  )
    public String getAllowdrmcontent() {
        return this.allowdrmcontent;

    }

    public void setAllowdrmcontent(final String allowdrmcontent) {
        this.allowdrmcontent = allowdrmcontent;
    }


    @Basic( optional = true )
    @Column( length = 45  )
    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;

    }

    public void setCity(final String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "fkUser"  )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @Basic( optional = true )
    @Column( nullable = true  )
    public Set<CmsUserAllowedContType> getCmsUserAllowedContTypes() {
        return this.cmsUserAllowedContTypes;

    }


    public void addCmsUserAllowedContType(CmsUserAllowedContType cmsUserAllowedContType) {
        cmsUserAllowedContType.setFkUser(this);
        this.cmsUserAllowedContTypes.add(cmsUserAllowedContType);
    }


    public void setCmsUserAllowedContTypes(final Set<CmsUserAllowedContType> cmsUserAllowedContType) {
        this.cmsUserAllowedContTypes = cmsUserAllowedContType;
    }

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "fkCmsUser"  )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @Basic( optional = true )
    @Column( nullable = true  )
    public Set<CmsUserFtpDetails> getCmsUserFtpDetailss() {
        return this.cmsUserFtpDetailss;

    }


    public void addCmsUserFtpDetails(CmsUserFtpDetails cmsUserFtpDetails) {
        cmsUserFtpDetails.setFkCmsUser(this);
        this.cmsUserFtpDetailss.add(cmsUserFtpDetails);
    }

    public void setCmsUserFtpDetailss(final Set<CmsUserFtpDetails> cmsUserFtpDetails) {
        this.cmsUserFtpDetailss = cmsUserFtpDetails;
    }



    @Basic( optional = true )
    @Column( length = 45  )
    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;

    }

    public void setCountry(final String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 45  )
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;

    }



    /**  
     * Set the value related to the column: createdBy.
     * @param createdBy the createdBy value you wish to set
     */
    public void setCreatedBy(final String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: createdOn.
     * @return A Date object (this.createdOn)
     */
    @Basic( optional = true )
    @Column( name = "created_on"  )
    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return this.createdOn;

    }



    /**  
     * Set the value related to the column: createdOn.
     * @param createdOn the createdOn value you wish to set
     */
    public void setCreatedOn(final Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: email.
     * @return A String object (this.email)
     */
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( nullable = false, length = 45  )
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;

    }



    /**  
     * Set the value related to the column: email.
     * @param email the email value you wish to set
     */
    public void setEmail(final String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: firstName.
     * @return A String object (this.firstName)
     */
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 30  )
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;

    }



    /**  
     * Set the value related to the column: firstName.
     * @param firstName the firstName value you wish to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }


    @ManyToOne( cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_role_id", nullable = false )
    public CmsRoleMaster getFkRole() {
        return this.fkRole;

    }

    public void setFkRole(final CmsRoleMaster fkRole) {
        this.fkRole = fkRole;
    }

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "id", nullable = false  )
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;

    }

    public void setId(final Integer id) {
        // If we've just been persisted and hashCode has been
        // returned then make sure other entities with this
        // ID return the already returned hash code
        if ( (this.id == null || this.id == 0) &&
                (id != null) &&
                (this.hashCode != null) ) {
        SAVED_HASHES.put( id, this.hashCode );
        }
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 30  )
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;

    }

    public void setLastName(final String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Basic( optional = true )
    @Column( name = "modified_on"  )
    public Date getModifiedOn() {
        return this.modifiedOn;

    }

    public void setModifiedOn(final Date modifiedOn) {
        this.modifiedOn = modifiedOn;
    }

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( nullable = false, length = 45  )
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;

    }

    public void setPassword(final String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Basic( optional = true )
    @Column( name = "phone_number"  )
    public Long getPhoneNumber() {
        return this.phoneNumber;

    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(final Long phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Integer getPincode() {
        return this.pincode;

    }

    public void setPincode(final Integer pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( nullable = false, length = 45  )
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;

    }

    public void setUsername(final String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a current session and an active transaction so that the collection can be lazily loaded. Alternatively, change the load mode of the collection to eager fetching.

Comment: sample example for the same. I am sharing my repository below:public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<CmsUser, Integer>{
 
 User findByUsernameAndPassword(String username);
 
}

Comment: 1 more doubt. If my user table is related in 10 different table. Using EAGER will load data from all the tables. And if each table have 10000 records, then my object will be a huge. Is my statement true.

Comment: I got the answer for my questions. @transactional annotation on my service method did the trick. using this annotation my hibernate session is alive for longer time.